# Regular expression to extract data from a colum and put it in another column

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-match

I have a MySQL table with few columns.

Column 1 contains html code:

```
<p style="xxx"><img src="path/to/file.png(or jpg)"></p>
```

I want to extract the `src` (path/file.xxx) to column 2, and then remove the whole P tag from column 1.

I tried few techniques like

```
preg_match('/\< *[img][^\>]*[src] *= *[\"\']{0,1}([^\"\']*)/i', $row->image, $matches);
```

But nothing seems to work.

Anything simple and light to use?

Comment: You do not want to use `[...]` blocks around `img` and `src`. `< *img[^\>]*src *= *["']?([^"'>]+)["'][^>]*>` seems to match fine: http://regex101.com/r/qC9pD7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` represents a character set, not a sequence of a characters.

```
$html = '<p style="xxx"><img src="path/to/file.png(or jpg)"></p>';
preg_match('/<img src="([^"]*)">/', $html, $m);
echo $m[0] . "\n";
echo $m[1] . "\n";
```

outputs:

```
<img src="path/to/file.png(or jpg)">
path/to/file.png(or jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

With all the disclaimers about using regex to handle html, you can use a simple `preg_replace`:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~<p[^>]*><img src="([^"]+)"></p>~', '$1', $yourstring);
```

**Explanation**

- `<p` matches the beginning of the tag
- `[^>]*` matches any chars that are not a `>`
- `><img src="` matches literal characters
- The parentheses in `([^"]+)` capture any chars that are not a `"` to Group 1 (this is what you want)
- `"></p>` matches chars to Group 1
- We replace the whole string with `$1`, which is a backreference to the content captured by Group 1